Find the trend of logged in users by sifting through nginx logs in grafana
I have in grafana logs of loki which are pushed via fluentbit.
I want to see visualisation such that I see #active users at an hourly interval. My first attempt at it is in loki query like so:
count(sum by (log_http_headers_authorization) (count_over_time({container="/nginx", hostname="whirlpool-prod"} | json [1m])))

where authorization is a headers containing hashed "Authorization token" (its hashed so no security issues). Each token corresponds to a unique login. All the APIs from a logged in user's session will have the same authorization value.
The issue with above query is that output from sum by subquery returns >500 series (for 3 hour duration):

maximum of series (500) reached for a single query

I'm inclined to believe this has to be not such a complex thing that cannot be solved inside grafana (and without hitting the 500 series limit). Essentially if there's any other way to achieve it, that is totally acceptable.

Are you sure the error you are getting is caused by the error in question? I've run similar query on play.grafana.com it provided expected result, will error happens when outer count is missing

The error is only when total number of sessions > 500. Below that for smaller duration query runs fine.

I'd want to know if there's a scalable way to handle this, since the total unique sessions in system for a day can be in 10K's.
